# Why do I get this `TypeMismatchException` with Spring

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I'm trying to use Hibernate with Spring in Eclipse. I get the following error when I try to run the welcome file on the server:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mySessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: 
    Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is 
    org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.util.ArrayList' to required type 'java.lang.Class[]' for property 'annotatedClasses'; 
    nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find class [com.vaannila.domain.User]
```

The class `com.vaannila.domain.User` is in the Java Resources:src folder of the project in eclipse. Why isn't it being located?

Comment: Your title is a bit misleading. Consider changing it.

Comment: We'll need to see `dispatcher-servlet.xml` before we can answer that

Comment: possible duplicate of [class not found exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153539/class-not-found-exception)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From time to time Eclipse is a bit picky about deploying a project correctly. It seems that it has to do with the installed plugins. When this happens to me in the 'Servers'-view of the 'Debug'-Perspective i click the 'add and remove' menu and remove my project from deployment - save it - add it again and redeploy. Usually this does the trick.
Another try is to start Eclipse with the -clean option.