# class not found exception

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, spring

i'm trying to run a web application in eclipse using springs and hibernate.

the dispatcher-servlet.xml is,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <bean id="myDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/test"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="mysql"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.vaannila.domain.User</value>
            </list>
        </property>


        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="myUserDAO" class="com.vaannila.dao.UserDAOImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean name="/user/*.htm" class="com.vaannila.web.UserController" >
        <property name="userDAO" ref="myUserDAO" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

the error i get is,

---

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mySessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.util.ArrayList' to required type 'java.lang.Class[]' for property 'annotatedClasses'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find class [com.vaannila.domain.User]
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:563)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:900)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:455)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:442)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:339)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:306)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:849)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:454)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
```

---

The class `com.vaannila.domain.User` is in the Java Resources:src folder of the project in eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Check that class should be there in `src/com/vannila/domain/User.java`
2. check that class is annotated as shown [here](http://www.vaannila.com/spring/spring-hibernate-integration-1.html).and compare where you missed the thing

Comment: The class is there and dispatcher-servlet.xml is also the same.. i've made modifications only to reflect i'm using mysql

Comment: I hope basic annotations are there

Answer (score 2):

Always check the 'Problems" tab/view in eclipse. i was getting the same issue and reason was simple that i included "org.springframework.spring-library-3.1.0.RELEASE.libd" file as library when i was configuring the build path and this was in the same "dist" folder. so i just removed that and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please create package in eclipse and add User.java to the package.

Comment: the packages that i create are placed in the Java Resources:src folder.

Answer (score 0):

i try the code, and everything is working fine.

at first i suspect `<list>` will give the instance of List not array, but when i try it, it doing fine.

spring will throw error like you write above if they cannot find the class that you suppose to include in this case `com.vaannila.domain.User`

check your output folder for compiled class. is there User.class exist and successfully compiled?

Answer (score 0):

It is easy, it is the collision happened in the library you include .please check the lib you included, in the path :

```
   tomcat6/webapps/<you project name>/WEB-INF/lib/
```

you possible find two file named like : asm.jar and asm-2.x.x.jar
the two jar file come from different source, one from the spring the other from hibernate,so there is some collision happened here, tomcat cannot decide which jar to added.so it report the exception.